# how to fix custom timeline problem JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have seen this timeline build [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c24hTB9cKfM) then I have tried to make I timeline using hbox and sperators and labels, but I fall in a representation errors

the following controller allows me to build this timeline this above nodes

```
public class GuiMainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML 
    private BorderPane borderPane; 

    public void getUnit1(){
        //This will fill the Time Line Unit in your Gui
                VBox vbox = new VBox();
                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.setManaged(false);
                for (int i =0; i < 24; i++) {
                    //For each unit create a new instance
                    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
                    anchorPane.setPrefHeight(30);
                    anchorPane.setPrefWidth(66);

                    Separator separatorR = new Separator();
                    separatorR.setLayoutX(66);
                    separatorR.setLayoutY(14);
                    separatorR.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
                    separatorR.setPrefHeight(15);

                    Separator separatorM = new Separator();
                    separatorM.setLayoutY(14);
                    separatorM.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
                    separatorM.setPrefHeight(15);

                    Separator separatorL = new Separator();
                    separatorL.setLayoutX(33);
                    separatorL.setLayoutY(20);
                    separatorL.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
                    separatorL.setPrefHeight(10);
                    separatorL.setPrefWidth(6);

                    Label lblT = new Label();
                    lblT.setText(i+"h");

                    Label lblTT = new Label();
                    lblTT.setLayoutX(66);
                    lblTT.setText((i+1)+"h");

                    anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(separatorL,lblT,separatorM,separatorR,lblTT);
                    hbox.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
                }
                borderPane.getChildren().add(hbox);
    }
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        getUnit1();
    }
}
```

[image]

How can I made this timeline, any help are appreciated to get some like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho you shouldn't get any layouts involved here, since this way you rely on the exact implementation of those layouts. Furthermore I'm not sure `Seperator` should be involved here. You could use a `Path` though and calculate the positions of all the lines on the axis.

```
private static Label createLabel(String text, double layoutY, double majorTickDistance, int index) {
    Label label = new Label(text);

    // label width should be exactly the distance between ticks
    label.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    label.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    label.setPrefWidth(majorTickDistance);

    // center text
    label.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    label.setLayoutY(layoutY);

    // align center of the label with major tick
    label.setLayoutX((index + 0.5) * majorTickDistance);
    return label;
}

/**
 * @param majorTickDistance the width between major ticks
 * @param minorTicks the number of minor ticks between major ticks
 * @param majorTickHeight the height of major tick markers
 * @param minorTickHeight the height of minor tick markers
 * @param firstText the first text for the first major tick
 * @param text the text for other ticks
 */
private static Pane createAxis(double majorTickDistance, int minorTicks,
        double majorTickHeight, double minorTickHeight, String firstText, String... text) {
    final double labelY = majorTickHeight + 3;
    final double minorTickDistance = majorTickDistance / minorTicks;

    // initialize path with first major tick and horizontal line
    Path path = new Path(
            new MoveTo(0, 0), new HLineTo(majorTickDistance * text.length),
            new MoveTo(0, 0), new VLineTo(majorTickHeight)
    );

    // add path and first label
    Pane pane = new Pane(path, createLabel(firstText, labelY, majorTickDistance, -1));

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        double offset = i * majorTickDistance;

        // add minor ticks
        for (int j = 1; j < minorTicks; j++) {
            double x = offset + j * minorTickDistance;
            path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(x, 0), new VLineTo(minorTickHeight));
        }
        offset += majorTickDistance;

        // add major tick at the end of the current interval
        path.getElements().addAll(new MoveTo(offset, 0), new VLineTo(majorTickHeight));

        // add label below major tick
        pane.getChildren().add(createLabel(text[i], labelY, majorTickDistance, i));
    }

    pane.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    return pane;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(createAxis(30, 5, 10, 5, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")), 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```